# Can I unambiguously define both a stream operator and a conversion operator?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a class which has both overloaded `operator<<` and `operator>>` friend functions, *and* an `operator std::string` method, something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    operator std::string()

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const MyClass&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const MyClass&);
};
```

What I find is that my compiler complains about "ambiguous overload" of the stream operators when I try to use them. I *think* it's because if I write this:

```
myStream << MyClass();
```

The compiler doesn't know whether to use the `operator<<` for `MyClass`, or to use the `operator std::string` for `MyClass` first, and then use the `operator<<` for `std::string` (defined in the standard library) to write into the stream.

Is this actually the cause? If so, is there any way to get around it? I know in C++11 you can use the `explicit` keyword on conversion operators to prevent implicit conversions, but the project I'm working on is currently compiled as C++03.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The `operator<<` should be unambiguously preferred. What compiler are you using?

Comment: You need to show a small sample of complete code that actually exhibits your problem.  Assuming mystream is a std::ostream (or a type derived from std::ostream) then your example as it stands (apart from need to add a missing semi-colon and include needed standard headers) will not exhibit the problem you describe.  That is true with all C++ standards since 1998.  Either there is some other contributor in your code that you are not showing (likely) or your compiler does not comply with the standard in relevant ways (possible, but relatively unlikely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, keyword explicit has existed since the 1998 standard. Are you sure your compiler does not support it?

Moreover, I was skeptical about your explanation because the expression std::cout << MyClass() is a perfect match for your overload of operators << and >>, assuming your 'myStream' is of the corresponding stream type. A perfect match takes precedence over any match that requires user defined conversions. Indeed, the following code compiled just fine for me. Which compiler are you using?

```
class MyClass {
public:
    operator std::string();

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const MyClass&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const MyClass&);
};

void just_do_it()
{
    std::cout << MyClass();
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about `explicit` regarding the conversion operator (not the `explicit` regarding constructors) which is new in C++11, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit).

Comment: That's very likely the case James. Thank you. Regardless, there is no possible ambiguity that I can see in finding the matching overload, unless his 'myStream' is at fault.

Comment: Just testing it out isn't really enough to verify the expected result in the general case. Compilers could implement it differently or there could be undefined behaviour involved. So just saying "compile it and see" is not really a valid answer in my book.

Comment: @Liondance thanks for answering. I'm aware that my example compiles with the latest clang compiler on my personal machine. Unfortunately I can't (or rather don't know of a way) compile arbitrary test programs using the compiler I use at work -- it's a custom cross-compiler (based on some older GCC build) targeted at a proprietary OS (based on FreeBSD) and the workflow doesn't typically involve direct invocation. I'm marking your answer as accepted because the line about "a perfect match takes precedence over any match that requires user defined conversions" does answer my question.